# How to make a selected monitor showing black by pressing a joystick button?

Tags: multiple-monitors, autohotkey, hotkeys, joystick

I would like to blank and reveal a given monitor by the press of a joystick button.

I found the tool MultiscreenBlank2 which can blank and reveal a selected monitor.

I try to use the tool AutoHotKey to bind a hotkey to start MultiscreenBlank2. So far I am struggeling how to make it work with using only one hotkey.

But then I still need to bind a hotkey to a joystick button and I don't have any solution for that so far.

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

meanwhile I found out a way to do that using a tool called MultiscreenBlank and/or MultiscreenBlank2 in combination with the tool EventGhost. Using the included plugin Joystick for EventGhost it's possible to capture any joystick button (at least my buttonboxes are working perfectly fine) and bind it to an action. Which is to start MultiscreenBlank to toggle an and off a selected monitor which can be addressed via parameters.

cheers,
Bernhard